# Is it possible to integrate AWS sagemaker and delta lake

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, delta-lake

Is it possible to integrate AWS sage maker and delta lake?

thanks
Ramabadran

Comment: what is the task? what do you want to achieve? Answer is most probably yes, but it really depends on what do you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though it depends on what part of SageMaker you mean (Training, Notebook, Inference, etc).

Last week, an integration between SageMaker and Delta Lake was documented here (custom docker in the SageMaker Processing API)

https://github.com/eitansela/sagemaker-delta-sharing-demo/tree/main/delta_lake_bring_your_own_container_processing